# form_for being submitting by 2 links, how to I tell which was used when I am back in the controller?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, submit, form-for, link-to

I putting a form together, but for design reason the form must be submitted by a link.
I found out how to perform that:

```
= link_to_function "Next >>", "$(this).up('form').submit()"
```

This will do, and I can create many link with this no problem. However I don't know how to distinguish which link was used to bring me back to the controller ?
I need to perform slightly different depending on the link...

Any idea ? I have tried to embed some javascript, etc. but I could not figure it out.

Thanks,

Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
= link_to_function "Next >>", "$('#hidden_field').value = 1;$(this).up('form').submit()"
= link_to_function "Next 2 >>", "$('#hidden_field').value = 2;$(this).up('form').submit()"
```

Assuming you're using jquery, set a hidden field to different values depending on which link was clicked. The 2nd parameter to link_to_function is merely javascript, after all.

Comment: Thanks ! Quick question, because I have been researching this online quite a bit, and many suggest not doing this but rather style "down" the submit button ? What's your take on that ? Which is a better solution, compatibility wise, etc. ?

Comment: I don't get it, it always tells me whatever name I put on the javascript that it's null. All the other element in my forms are of type authors[field_name] and I declare my hidden field: hidden_field, :action, what should the #hidden_field be replaced by ?

Comment: Probably #action, or maybe #authors_action. Check the generated HTML for whatever id is on the field.