# Rails remote link_to and access to trigger element in javascript response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery

in my Rails3 application I have table with rows, each containig link_to with :remote => true

```
...
<tr><td><%= link_to "remote call", action_controller_path(data), :remote => true %>
...
```

As response to ajax call I return javascript to execute in browser:

```
# action.js.erb
console.log(this); <-- "this" is browser's window object not my element
$(this).closest("tr")....
```

The problem is, that in my javascript I need access to element, which triggered the ajax call (the `<a>` tag). Is there any way how to get access to it?

Comment: This is a similar question that has been asked before, let me find the links.

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer to a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781824/rails-access-ajax-triggering-element-in-callback).

---

> My solution was to bind a pre-submit class to the element, in my case
>   a popup modal window.  It's a similar solution to the post linked to
>   above in that it uses the pre-submit bindings, but tailored to use
>   classes instead.
>
> In public/javascripts/application.rb:
>
> ```
> jQuery(function($) { 
>   $(".poppable").bind("ajax:loading", function() { $(this).addClass("popped"); });
> });
> ```
>
> Then in my view for the popup content (e.g.
>   app/views/mymodel/popup.js.erb):
>
> ```
> var p = $(".poppable.popped");
> p.removeClass("popped");
> /* Do what I need to with p ... */
> ```
>
> If this doesn't look kosher, I'm all ears but it works for now.